# Calculating Date Difference in SharePoint using column Condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have sharepoint list to track projects:

1. Date Started
2. Date Completion
3. Project Status (On-going, Completed, Hold, Cancelled)

I want to compute the number of days the project was completed.

If isblank[Completion Dated], today()-[date started] else [Date completion]- [Date Started]

How do I write this in the calculated formula?

Answer (score 0):

Use formula like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Completion]), Today()-[Date Started], [Date Completion]-[Date Started])
```

Note: Calculated column will be evaluated only when list item is added/updated or calculated column formula is updated.

Comment: Thank you. Was hitting error using ISBLANK statement.  What i did is try below and it worked: =IF([Actual Completion ]=0,DATEDIF([Start Date],TODAY(),"D"),[Actual Completion ]-[Start Date])

Comment: Great, glad you found the solution!

Comment: Please [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.